# Ограничения VK-APi

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, python-3.x

Есть standalone-приложение на python, которое делает запросы к vk-api.
Иногда запросом является `users.search()`.

От запуска к запуску бывают странности:

Подаю методу `search()` ФИО Иван Иванов и год рождения 10.10.1910.
Первый запуск, все хорошо, получил список юзеров удовлетворяющих этому критерию, например их всего один.
Второй запуск, параметры такие же, и vk возвращает, что ничего не найдено.

Где я ошибаюсь, когда запрос один и тот же? Как это исправить?
С чем такая работа vk api может быть связана? Ограничения на api-вызов в промежуток времени (секунда, минута)?

Comment: Уверены, что ВК отвечает именно пустым результатом, а не какой-либо ошибкой?

Comment: да. я поговорил с support vk они пояснили про ограничения на количество запросов в единицу времени.

Comment: т.е. дело было в частых запросах? В таком случае ВК [возвращает ошибку](https://vk.com/dev/errors) #6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как метод `users.search` не требует прав доступа, то на него не распространяется ограничение в 3 запроса в секунду (если вы не передаёте `access_token` в запросе).

Однако недавно экспериментальным путём я выяснил, что при обращении к Вк, сервер API может возвращать ответ на запрос в течение длительного промежутка времени (более 3 минут).
В данном случае от нас как от пользователей ничего не зависит. Попробуйте увеличить ваше время ожидания ответа на запрос.