# Ограничения на поиск пользователей через users.search api vk

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

У api вконтакте есть ограничение - 3 запроса в секунду. Однако у `users.search` есть какое-то своё ограничение на количество вызовов.

> Помимо ограничений на частоту обращений, существуют и количественные
>   ограничения на вызов однотипных методов. По понятным причинам, мы не
>   предоставляем информацию о точных лимитах.

Нужно найти 1000 человек в соцсети (клиенты компании). Если api бы работало хорошо, это было бы 300 секунд. А что делать с тем, что на N-м запросе api выдаёт 0 найденных? Похоже, что N-порядка десятков.
Другие методы работают, а этот выдаёт 0. Причём даже если попытаться поискать людей просто в браузере - тоже 0 найденных.

Кто сталкивался, поясните, надолго ли происходит такое отключение поиска. И может есть какое-то время паузы, выше которого поиск всегда работает и возвращает результаты?

[Проверка через execute тут](https://vk.com/dev/execute)

```
var found = API.users.search({"q":"Иванов Иван"});
return found;
```

Запуск этого кода даёт `response: { count: 0, items: [] }`, когда `users.search` вдруг перестаёт работать.

Comment: Похоже, что не только `users.search` подвержен ограничению, но и `wall.search`. Проверено, "банят" довольно быстро с теми же симптомами, что и в вопросе. К сожалению, не удалось вычислить момент, с какого по счёту запроса это началось. Вполне вероятно, что `audio.search`, а также `video.search` тоже весьма ограничены.

Comment: @alexis031182 честно говоря, из-за этой неоднозначности не очень хочется с ними работать, не беру работу по их апи больше. Программирование и нечёткие правила несовместимы.

Comment: Если допустимое кол-во запросов будет известно заранее, то ботописатели обойдут ограничение, путём использования в парсере неограниченного количества учётных записей, коих в сети можно покупать, хоть пачками. А тут получается, что возврат нулевого значения не гарантирует в любой момент времени, что поиск не обнаружил данные по запрашиваемой строке. Может они есть, а может аккаунт уже забанен. Это ведёт к тому, что нужно выполнять отдельный запрос с заранее проверенным на корректность результатом на каждый нулевой ответ. Это конечно позволит проверить достоверность ответа, но сильно снизит КПД.

Comment: Но нельзя не согласиться с тем, что эта мера с неизвестным лимитом сильно портит жизнь и тем, кто готов играть по правилам. Видимо, выбирая защиту от злоупотреблений, недовольством соблюдающих правила пользователей решили пренебречь.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ограничения VK-APi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437164/%d0%9e%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-vk-api)